# Get jQuery element reference from ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have a semi arbitrary length ng-repeat with a "tag along" element that gets rendered based on some criteria:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] track by $index">my repeat</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-if="shouldRender(day)" class="maybe">maybe rendered</div>
```

What I want to do is set a click event on the repeated element and reference the NEXT SIBLING "maybe rendered" element in order to do some jQuery magic. So what I want to do is add `ng-click="getNextMaybe(this)"` and process it to find the next sibling `.maybe` element. So now I have:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] track by $index" ng-click="getNextMaybe(this)">my repeat</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-if="shouldRender(day)" class="maybe">maybe rendered</div>

function myCtrl($scope){
  $scope.getNextMaybe = function(repeatElem){
    var nextMaybe = $(repeatElem).next('.maybe');
  }
}
```

I think I'm sort of confused as to what `this` is in this instance and how I can turn it into a jQuery object to do my processing.

Thanks!

Comment: Messing with the DOM in your controller is considered bad practice, there may be another way to do what you want.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you must do this, do it in a directive where you have element access. Most likely there are more angular ways to do what you need

Comment: directive is probably the best option thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `$event` to your function and look at `$event.target` to get the element ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gc9cJmSqOV7xzfK4qYC8?p=preview)):

```
<button ng-click="onClick($event)">Button</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.onClick = function(evt) {
  console.dir(evt.target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer to my question however a directive is probably the best way to handle stuff like this in retrospect.